# sIFR and JS dynamic content

Tags: javascript, sifr

Hi I made a function to use sIFR

```
function sifrz() {
    var geosans = { src: 'sifr3-r436/flash/geosans.swf' };
    sIFR.activate(geosans);
    sIFR.replace(geosans, {
    selector: '#title,#descr',
    css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #7d7e7e; color: #000000; }, a { color: #000000; }, a:hover { color: #000000; }'
 });
}
```

then I've got another function to change my title text
I tried to reinit sIFR after updating text using `sIFR.redraw();` and `sifrz()`
but it won't work

```
function load_title(url, titolo, descr, id_filmato) {
 $("#title").html("Test");
 sIFR.redraw();
    sifrz();
}
```

Can you help?

I'm using sIFR version 3, revision 436.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with sIFR, but what happens if you move the sifrz before the sIFR.redraw?

Answer (score 0):

Split the replacements for `#title` and `#descr` into two. Then run `sIFR.replacements["#title"][0].replaceText("Test")` to change the text in the title movie.